# Powershell - Outputting .txt data to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I hope you could help a PowerShell beginner in outputting data from a .txt file to a CSV.

Things to be keep in mind:

- Each text file contains more than one entry that needs extraction
- Terminal will always be A followed by 3 digits
- Enquirer will always start with C but can be different lengths
- There are two Date of Birth patterns in the file
- The spaces aren't tab delimited in the txt nor are they all the same spacing amount.

This is the CSV output I would like (Apologies I haven't got enough rep to upload a picture!)

```
+------------+------+----------+----------+-------------------+----------+
| Date       | Time | Terminal | Enquirer | Enquiry           | DOB      |
+------------+------+----------+----------+-------------------+----------+
| 29/05/2017 | 1227 | A999     | CA75849  | DOE/JOHN          |  / /1988 |
+------------+------+----------+----------+-------------------+----------+
| 29/05/2017 | 1424 | A999     | CA75849  | SMITH/SIMON/PETER |  / /1967 |
+------------+------+----------+----------+-------------------+----------+
|            |      |          |          |                   |          |
+------------+------+----------+----------+-------------------+----------+
```

Example of data .txt file

```
START                 TERMINAL    USER        ENQUIRER                  TERMINAL IP

========================================================================================================================

29/05/17 1227       A999        CA75849       8875849 OCBA NCPS RBC/12/1960



        SEARCH REF                      NAME : DOE/JOHN PAGE CODE =  

                                    DATE OF BIRTH :   /  /1988




========================================================================================================================
29/05/17 1424       A999        CA75849       8875849 OCBA NCPS RBC/60/2111                                

        SEARCH REF                        NAME : SMITH/SIMON/PETER CHAPTER CODE =  

                                    DATE OF BIRTH :   /  /1967


========================================================================================================================
```

Please don't faint over my crap Powershell script.

The best I have managed to get is having the right information but 'System.Object[]' in the cells rather than the actual string of results.

```
$XmlDocument = Get-Content -Path "C:\Script Projects\Log\880006.txt"
$TodaysCSV = "C:\Script Projects\Log\880006.csv"

$TopLine = $XmlDocument | Select-String "A1" 
$Enquiry = $XmlDocument | Select-String "Search"
$DOB = $XmlDocument | Select-String "BIRTH"

$toptop = $topline -split " "

$Date = $toptop | Select-String -Pattern "^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}$"
$Time = $toptop | Select-String -Pattern "^\d{4}$"
$Terminal = $toptop | Select-String -Pattern "^A\d{3}$"
$Enquirer = $toptop | Select-String -Pattern "C\w\d{5}" 

$csv = New-Object -TypeName PSObject 

Add-Member -InputObject $csv -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date"  -Value $Date
Add-Member -InputObject $csv -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Time"  -Value $Time
Add-Member -InputObject $csv -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Terminal"  -value $Terminal
Add-Member -InputObject $csv -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Enquirer"  -value $Enquirer
Add-Member -InputObject $csv -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Enquiry"  -value $Enquiry
Add-Member -InputObject $csv -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DOB"  -value $DOB


$csv | Export-Csv $TodaysCSV -NoTypeInformation
```

I get this output

```
    +-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| Date            | Time            | Terminal        | Enquirer        | Enquiry         | DOB             |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| System.Object[] | System.Object[] | System.Object[] | System.Object[] | System.Object[] | System.Object[] |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|                 |                 |                 |                 |                 |                 |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|                 |                 |                 |                 |                 |                 |
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

I have tried this way too but I only get the date or playing around I can get all the data but only in the single column

```
$Total2 = "$date2", "$time2", "$Terminal2", "$Enquirer", "$Enquiry" 

$Columns = "Date", "Time", "Terminal", "Enquirer", "Enquiry"

$total2 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $Columns| export-csv $TodaysCSV -NoTypeInformation
```

But can't remember how I did it and still wont let me display it horizontally if I import from that file back into PowerShell and export as CSV.

The best I managed to get was this

```
Date    
----    
29/05/17
29/05/17




Time
----
1227
1424




Terminal
--------
A999    
A999    




Enquirer
--------
CA75849 
CA75849 




Enquiry                                                                         
-------                                                                         
SEARCH REF                      NAME : DOE/JOHN CHAPTER CODE =        
SEARCH REF                      NAME : SMITH/SIMON/PETER CHAPTER CODE =
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Looks like you need to add a select object before you export to csv - try this:     `$csv | select @{ l = "Date"; e = {$_.date} }, @{ l = "Time"; e = {$_.time} } | export-csv $TodaysCSV -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: `@{l='date';e={$_.date}` < this is unnecessary.  `-Property Date, Time` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have got further with Don's suggestion, Incorrigible when I used your suggestion it still output the data as System.Object[] in the cells

I now have this information, which is nearly there. I just need to split the two results into separate rows. Here's the data now (if I add -delimiter " " in export-csv it doesn't like it. If I do -delimiter "`t" it puts all the data into a single column.

FYI the data is split with a single space ie. 29/05/2017 29/05/2017

Is the -delimiter " " a valid representation for a 'space'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used a different approach,

- splitting the file into sections delimited with the dash line and
- 3 different RegExes using named (capture groups) to grep the properties of each line type.
  The first on [RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/r/EPcJYg/1)
- all found properties are stored in an intermediate $Row object and if all RegEx matched gathered in `$Csv`

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\06\SO_51209341.ps1
$FileIn   = '.\SO_51209341_data.txt'
$TodayCsv = '.\SO_51209341_data.csv'

$RE1 = [RegEx]'(?m)(?<Date>\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}) (?<Time>\d{4}) +(?<Terminal>A\d{3}) +(?<User>C[A-Z0-9]+) +(?<Enquirer>.*)$'
$RE2 = [RegEx]'\s+SEARCH REF\s+NAME : (?<Enquiry>.+?) (PAGE|CHAPTER) CODE ='
$RE3 = [RegEx]'\s+DATE OF BIRTH : (?<DOB>[0-9 /]+?/\d{4})'

$Sections = (Get-Content $FileIn -Raw) -split "={30,}`r?`n" -ne ''

$Csv = ForEach($Section in $Sections){
    $Row= @{} | Select-Object Date,Time,Terminal,User,Enquirer,Enquiry,DOB
    $Cnt = 0
    If ($Section -match $RE1){++$Cnt
        $Row.Date     = $Matches.Date
        $Row.Time     = $Matches.Time
        $Row.Terminal = $Matches.Terminal
        $Row.User     = $Matches.User
        $Row.Enquirer = $Matches.Enquirer.Trim()
    }
    If ($Section -match $RE2){++$Cnt
        $Row.Enquiry  = $Matches.Enquiry
    }
    If ($Section -match $RE3){++$Cnt
        $Row.DOB      = $Matches.DOB
    }
    if ($Cnt -eq 3){$Row}
}

$csv | Format-Table
$csv | Export-Csv $Todaycsv -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output **revised version**

```
> . Q:\Test\2018\07\06\SO_51209341.ps1

Date     Time Terminal User    Enquirer                      Enquiry           DOB
----     ---- -------- ----    --------                      -------           ---
29/05/17 1227 A999     CA75849 8875849 OCBA NCPS RBC/12/1960 DOE/JOHN            /  /1988
29/05/17 1424 A999     CA75849 8875849 OCBA NCPS RBC/60/2111 SMITH/SIMON/PETER   /  /1967
```

Comment: Fantastic! Regex to the rescue.

Comment: WOW!! This is perfect! All data is nicely formatted and everything.

Spoke to the user these logs relate to, and the goalposts have moved ever so slightly...

There are a couple of results they require

The Enquirer Field needs the whole line after A999 (As this changes from log to log) A999 is the only thing that stays the same

Also there is a line of text I had removed from the top of the log which has USER ID - Line is

'SELECTED FOR OPERATOR  886667' 

This will always be 6 Digits and be worded the same.

I have tried adding this as another REGEX but not getting any results.

Comment: Your question is already quite complex. In my opinion it is answered to your requirements. You could honor this by [check marking as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Now to the changes, there is quite a gap after CA75849 should that be part of Enquirer? To match until line end $RE1 needs another setting `(?m)` multiline to match line begin `^` or line end '$'. I'll incorporate this change, but please try to work out further changes by yourself - [SO] isn't a script writing service. I like this type of tasks but don't expect  more effort from me.

Comment: Totally understand and can't thank you enough for what I've been staring at my screen struggling with every way possible and you nailed it! I'll try those changes and have marked as the answer

Comment: Hi I wondered If you could help with the USERID, I've been struggling since Monday to get it to REGEX the USERID in the text file.

It sits on the top section and only shows once as the file is a log for that user. Problem with the other fields are they are freetext so the user could input their user ID wrong.

I have tried lots of different REGEX patterns but doesn't pick up that line

I need extract the 891234 from the SELECTED FOR OPERATOR  891234

The text file is here (Called 891111.txt)
[link]https://regex101.com/r/UAYk1v/2[/link]Code Here

Comment: Sorry I had to edit the content as limited characters!

Comment: When I tried I managed to find the '89' but was getting it from the Filename and not the txt file

Is there any way of outputting the actual result of a REGEX query when in powershell?  I only seem to see true or false!

Comment: Hi LotPings I am struggling with this part. not sure if its because its on a different line but cannot seem to get the information I need (891234) from the SELECTED FOR OPERATOR line. 

Are you able to help? Many thanks

Comment: I just took a look at the page content you put into RegEx101 and this deviates from all you told before, `$RE2` and $RE3` can't match to changed line content there is no birth date etc. In total your changes messed all up. I suggest you clear up what the requirements really are and ask a new question with a [mcve]. Honestly, I feel being kidded.

Comment: Apologies, when I spoke to the users this is for I only got half the story, there were a number of details they failed to mention which in turn have made me look like an idiot. I really do appreciate the help you have given. I will create a new post and won't be offended if you don't want to go through it again!

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you need to convert objects to string before exporting.

To make your code working you can slightly modify object creation:

```
$csv = @()
for ($i = 0;$i -lt $Date.Length; $i++) {
$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject 
  Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Date"  -Value $Date[$i]
  Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Time"  -Value $Time[$i]
  Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Terminal"  -value $Terminal[$i]
  Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Enquirer"  -value $Enquirer[$i]
  Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Enquiry"  -value $Enquiry[$i]
  Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DOB"  -value $DOB[$i]
  $csv += $obj
}
```

#### Explanation:

The issue here is that you try to make a object of arrays while you should create array of objects. That's why when exporting you got `System.Object[]` instead of expected value.

**Note**: take a look at the code you pasted here and file format. This line:

```
$TopLine = $XmlDocument | Select-String "A1"
```

should be

```
$TopLine = $XmlDocument | Select-String "A999"
```

Comment: Consider using an ordered hashtable to create your objects much faster than `Add-Member 
ex: 

$hash = [ordered]@{ PropertyName = $Value; $Prop2 = $value2 }; New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $hash`

Comment: Another good practice which is hard for me to get used to... Thanks for reminder, I'll add that a bit later. Good point!